# Generate new variable by grouping an old one according to its value characteristic

Tags: variables, stata, generate

I want to `generate` a new variable in Stata by grouping an old one according to its value characteristics. I have one variable called `status` that reflects employment type and status, so it has values like "Manager", "Ex-Manager", "Employee", "Ex-Employee".

Now I want to `generate` a new dummy variable that equals 1 if the person is still employed (contains "Manager" and "Employee") and equals 0 if the person is no longer employed ("Ex-Employee", "Ex-Manager").

Comment: Are you referring to a numeric variable with value labels or a string variable, because the answer will vary accordingly. "Value characteristics" could mean either; it's not standard Stata terminology

Comment: @NickCox status is a string variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
generate wanted = inlist(status, "Manager", "Employee") if !missing(status)
```

will produce an indicator variable that is 1 if `status` is either of the specified values, 0 if it is another specified value, and missing if `status` is missing (meaning, an empty string).

See the help for `inlist()` and FAQs such as

https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-dummy-variables/

https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/

Note that the comparison is entirely literal (no incorrect spellings or extra spaces or characters).